# Pandas - Check if all elemets in a list columns are in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which  look like this:

```
   Name  Fruits                                                                                                                      
1  Bob  Apple,Banana
2  Sam  Apple,Orange
3  George Banana,Kiwi,Cherry
```

and another list that looks like this:

```
Allowed_fruits = [Apple,Banana]
```

I'm trying to write a test to check whatever all elements in the `Fruits` columns are in the `allowed_fruits` list.

If not - they should be inserted to another dataframe.

The output should be:

```
Found Not allowed Fruits !
  Name  Fruits                                                                                                                      
2  Sam  Orange
3  George Kiwi,Cherry
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Check this: `if all(set(item.split(',')) < set(allowed_fruits) for item in df['fruits'])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for new DataFrame with test in generator comprehension with with splitted values:

```
Allowed_fruits = ['Apple','Banana']

f = lambda x: ','.join(y for y in x.split(',') if y not in Allowed_fruits)
df1 = df.assign(Fruits = df['Fruits'].apply(f))
```

Or:

```
L = [','.join(y for y in x.split(',') if y not in Allowed_fruits) for x in df['Fruits']]
df1 = df.assign(Fruits = L)
```

and last reove rows with no values, comparing with empty string:

```
df1 = df1[df1['Fruits'].ne('')]
print (df1)
     Name       Fruits
2     Sam       Orange
3  George  Kiwi,Cherry
```

Comment: The first option didn't worked for me - but the second one works perfectly. Thank you so much !